# Subgradients of parametrized LP

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, subgradient

I'm dealing with this problem.

Let $\Lambda(y) := \max_{x\in P}c^\top x + y^\top x$

where $P$ is a polytope (a compact polyhedral set).

I need to characterize the subgradients of $\Lambda(\tilde{y})$ for fixed $\tilde{y}$.

Is there a way to write $\Lambda(\tilde{y})$ in terms of the extreme points of $P$ ?

Comment: Look up "parametric linear programming"

Comment: Just apply the definition. Assume that $P$ has $k$ extreme points $K=\{\bar{x}_1\ldots \bar{x}_k\}$. Then $$x \in P \leftrightarrow x=\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_k\bar{x}_k, \ \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i=1, \ \lambda_i\geq 0\ \forall i=1\ldots k$$

Comment: Yes, by doing so I'll have that for each fixed $\bar{y}$ there is a $\lambda^{\bar{y}}$, such that $x^\star_{\bar{y}} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k\lambda^{\bar{y}}_i\bar{x}_i$ is the optimum of the optimization problem, therefore

$$\Lambda(\bar{y}) = c^\top x^\star_{\bar{y}} + \bar{y}^\top x^\star_{\bar{y}}$$

The problem is that in order to characterize the subgradients I'll have (as it is differentiable)
$$\nabla\Lambda(\bar{y}) = c^\top\partial_\bar{y} x^{\star}_{\bar{y}} + (x^\star_{\bar{y}})^\top + \bar{y}^\top\partial_{\bar{y}}x^\star_{\bar{y}}$$
But I do not have a expression of those